# How to export the extended public key out of a Ledger Nano S?

Tags: public-key, ledger-nano-s

In order to provide secure use-once addresses to an application as a application developer I would like to export the public master key from a Nano S. Then I could derive many public keys from it and assign it to customers on request.

How can you optain the extended public key? [In the Ledger bitcoin UI this is possible](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/how-to-get-public-master-key-of-a-ledger-wallet) but for Ethereum?